# Preg_replace insert weird symbols at beginning and end

Tags: php, laravel, drupal, preg-replace

Been struggling for hours with this preg_replace thing..
I have it working on a live site made in drupal. Running PHP 5x
I'm in the process of recoding my site in Laravel running Php 7

My working code in my live site is

```
if(isset($getPost['message_tags'])) {

    $getPost = $getPost['message_tags'];
    foreach($getPost as $tags) {

        $tagId = $tags['id'];
        tagName = $tags['name'];
        $tag = '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/'.$tagId.'" target="_blank" title="'.$tagName.'">'.$tagName.'</a>'

        $message = preg_replace("/\@\[".$tagId."\]/", $tag, $message);
    }
}
```

It's iterating throug message tags (page mentioning) from facebook returned graph node to replace tags like this @[pageId] with actual links and its working perfectly on my live site...

But in my code for my Laravel site it inserting a **["** at beginning and **"]** and end of my string, and I can't figure why this is happening, been messing around with it for hours....
Have replaced the replacement with just a single word and apparently not that line doing it, seems like it's the replacement pattern itselv, but I'm puzzled why it's working on my live site. I imagine it's either a Laravel thing or Php 5 -> php 7 thing....? anyone?

Comment: Look at the resulting HTML. Running the function twice perhaps? Add some debugging notes. Otherwise showcase what `$getPost` really contains.

Comment: Well an example of $getPost would be

    `array:2 [  
  0 => array:5 [  
    "id" => "117406078460674"  
    "name" => "Rabalder - Gasolin' & Kim Larsen Kopi"  
    "type" => "page"  
    "offset" => 187  
    "length" => 37  
  ]  
  1 => array:5 [  
    "id" => "636466513042902"  
    "name" => "Hvis jeg var millionær"  
    "type" => "page"  
    "offset" => 305  
    "length" => 22  
  ]  
    ]`  
That how it looks in Laravels dd()

Comment: Oh And I can mention it IS doing the replace just as it should, working fine, just inserting those weird thing at start and end. And I dump and exit immediately after preg_replace to see , so cant be running more from there

Comment: OMG I actually figured it out and got it working... Think I've been messing with it 6-7 hours all night.. :-/ 
First of all, I actually forgot to USE the model I was fetching the $message string from in database, thats what actually made the weird symbols. That that wasn't there, just puffles me that Laravel didn't tellit was missing that class. After that it was just a matter og finetuning the query builder to get the $message just as a sting... Well, We learn everyday :-)